# PyQt: How to return a variable from a dialog function?

Tags: python, pyqt

I my trying to retrieve a string variable for the selected path.

```
class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):

def __init__(self):

    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)  

    A = self.in_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.browser)

def browser(self):
    global directory
    directory = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory())
    self.input_edit.setText(directory)
    return directory
```

The dialog open when I press the button but when I try to use A variable it's value is **None**. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
A = self.in_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.browser)
```

does not assign the result of `self.browser` but result of `clicked` signal to the variable `A`.
According to the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), signal `clicked` does not return anything. Therefore, since you are in a class, I recommend defining an attribute for the class and store result of `QFileDialog` in there.

```
class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.directory = None
        self.in_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.browser)

    def browser(self):
        self.directory = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory())
        self.input_edit.setText(directory)
```